# Using multiple operators in a while statement

Tags: java, operators, conditional-statements

Hi I'm trying to use both && and || operators in a while statement.I guess I can do it by using another 'while' but i was wondering if there is any way to do it by using them together.

```
while (month2<month1 && month2<1 || month2>12 ){
    System.out.println("Enter the return month (1-12) : ");
    month2 = input.nextInt();
    }
```

This is the part that I got problem with.It doesn't prompt user for the return month again even if it's smaller than pick-up month.

Comment: What is the problem? Don't do 2 whiles for many checks, this way is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you mean:

```
while (month2 < month1 && (month2 < 1 || month2 > 12))
```

Which says to iterate when one of: `month2 < 1` or `month2 > 12` is true; and when `month2 < month1`.

The implied order of operations of what you have written is:

```
(month2 < month1 && month2 < 1) || month2 > 12
```

Being explicit with parenthesis will allow you to check the right condition.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close.

```
while ((month2<1 || month2>12) && month2<month1){
  System.out.println("Enter the return month (1-12) : ");
  month2 = input.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need another set of parens:

```
while (month2 < month1 && (month2 < 1 || month2 > 12))
```